# annoying thread exceptions and is there any way to disable them?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading, roblox

I'm making a program in python that checks my cookies for various requests, it uses requests and threading, everything is good BUT - I get thread exceptions that annoy me badly, I've been searching a way to disable them or at least make them smaller for a while and didn't find any way, If someone could help it would be appreciated (sorry for my bad English)

The request it does:

```
r = req.get("https://api.roblox.com/users/account-info")
robux_balance = r.json()['RobuxBalance']
```

Screenshot of a thread exception:[image]

It is the only requests that errors for some reason.

Comment: Please post text, not images - see [ask].

Comment: But what is it that you want to happen? To stop the exception, just delete that line, but I'm guessing you need some data from the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in a try-except and pass in case of error

```py
r = req.get("https://api.roblox.com/users/account-info")

try:
   robux_balance = r.json()['RobuxBalance']
except KeyError:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception raises because your data dict did not have the key `RobuxBalance`. You should check the existence of the key before access it directly. I would use `r.json().get('RobuxBalance', None)` instead of directing accessing by key.

Answer (score 0):

That's an error in your code, nothing to do with the thread. You should check if the key is in your requests reply.

```
r = req.get("https://api.roblox.com/users/account-info")
if 'RobuxBalance' in r.json():
    robux_balance = r.json()['RobuxBalance']
else:
    do something like retry
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says 'RobuxBalance' not exists in the result dict.
two suggestions:

- add "try...except..." out the code;
- use `robux_balance = r.json().get('RobuxBalance')` instead.